# How to do dyadics-like operations in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have two 2-D arrays `A` and `B`. I want to get a 3-D array `C`, whose relation with `A` and `B` is:

```
C_mnl=A_mn*B_ml
```

How can I do this elegantly in numpy?

Comment: Have a look at [`numpy.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`numpy.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) can do that:

```
a = np.arange(6).reshape(3,2)  # a.shape = (3, 2)
b = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)  # b.shape = (3, 4)

c = np.einsum('mn,ml->mnl', a, b)  # c.shape = (3, 2, 4)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
C = A[...,None]*B[:,None,:]
```

**Explanation**

1. `A[...,None]` adds a new axis as the last axis with `None` (an equivalent for [`np.newaxis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis)) pushing all existing dimensions to the front. Thus, this would be same as `A[:,:,None]`.
2. Similarly with `B[:,None,:]`, it adds a new axis between the existing dimensions.
3. With steps `1` and `2`, we have the axes of the input arrays aligned and thus when operated with elementwise-multiplication would result in the desired output of shape `(m,n,l)` with `broadcasting`.

Comment: Good point. Sometimes it's just too easy to miss the simple solution :)

Comment: Can you explain a little more? I have searched the documentation but it seems no explanation exists for the usage of `...` and `None` in your answer.

Comment: @ChongWang Check out the edits if they help to understand.